# when opening DropdownMenu, how can I cancel keyboard auto-close behavior

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

when I open DropdownMenu, my keyboard auto-close. This behavior is not my expect.
I expect my keyboard to remain open when I open the DropdownMenu.

current behavior:

[image]

want behavior:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to my friends in the compose community for helping me with this on slack.

Just set the `properties.focusable` property to `false`

```kotlin
var content by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
var deadLineMenuExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center, horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
    TextField(value = content, onValueChange = {content = it})
    Box() {
        TextButton(onClick = { deadLineMenuExpanded = true }) {
            Text("open Menu")
        }
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = deadLineMenuExpanded,
            onDismissRequest = { deadLineMenuExpanded = false },
            properties = PopupProperties(focusable = false)
        ) {
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                deadLineMenuExpanded = false
            }) {
                androidx.compose.material.Text("today")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How to make it work with a physical keyboard? When the drop down menu is not focusable, it is not possible to go through the drop down items via a physical keyboard.